# Syntax error SQL query using UPDATE

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications, ms-access-2007

## Context

I added the option to modify the password and email address on my website. I have a microsoft Access Database. It has the columns "**EmailAddress**", "**Password**" and "**Username**" in the "**Login**" Table.

## Code

```vb
'For testing purposes, lets say :
VB_PasswordTXT = "1000:8NHLJo5oIDugFdzscuMrNSKyoNTRa0kI:6NSlpqGYC4zU2BG6cfJaHaPgVRCDPCc2"
VB_UserNameTXT = "Test123"
VB_EmailTXT = "a@mail.com"

Using thisConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""path""")
    Using thisCommand As OleDbCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand
        ' Open connection object
        thisConnection.Open()

        ' Initialize SQL SELECT command to retrieve desired data
        thisCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Login SET EmailAddress = @EmailAddress, Password = @Password " & _
                                "WHERE Username = @Username"
        thisCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", VB_UserNameTXT)
        thisCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", VB_EmailTXT)
        thisCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", VB_PasswordTXT)

        ' Create a DataReader object based on previously defined command object
        Dim thisReader As OleDbDataReader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader() 'Crashes here
        If thisReader.Read() Then
        End If

        thisReader.Close()
        thisConnection.Close()
    End Using
End Using
```

## Crash log

> Syntax error in the UPDATE command. (Free translation from French)

## Question

(As far as I know), the problem is coming from the `UPDATE` syntax. What is wrong in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password is a [reserved keyword](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx) in MS-Access.
When you have a field named in that way you should enclose it in square brakets

```
  thisCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Login SET EmailAddress = @EmailAddress, " & _
                            "[Password] = @Password " & _
                            "WHERE Username = @Username"
```

I suggest, if this is still possible, to change that name

And, while ExecuteReader works, the correct method to use for an UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE sql is

```
    thisCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Calling ExecuteReader is not good because you force it to create an OleDbDataReader not needed in case of an update.

**EDIT**
Reading your last comment I have noticed that you have your parameters added in the wrong order in the collection. OleDb doesn't recognize the parameters by their name but by their position in the parameters collection. You should add them in the exact order in which their respective placeholders appear in the command text (Move the username to be the last one added)

```
   thisCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Login SET EmailAddress = @EmailAddress, " & _ 
                             "[Password] = @Password " & _
                             "WHERE Username = @Username"
    thisCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", VB_EmailTXT)
    thisCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", VB_PasswordTXT)
    thisCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", VB_UserNameTXT)
```

Comment: Just as an addendum, it's good practice to put ALL table and column names in square brackets.

Comment: I'll accept the answer as it fixed my crash problem. (I have actually changed the column name for clarity). Now, I am trying to figure out why it doesn't actually **update** the value.. Thing is, I have other `UPDATE` queries that work properly. Oh well, thanks!

Comment: @Grim, it is much better practice to use an alias, thus eliminating the need for square brackets. No one should have spaces or reserved characters in field / column names.

Comment: @Fionnuala - well, yes, avoiding the issue in the first place by using non-reserved column names would be preferable :P

Comment: @grim Perhaps that was not clear, if you use an alias, you also avoid problems such as two columns from separate tables having the same name, as well as reserved words. For example `login.password` or `l.password` will work.

Comment: @Fionnuala - Yes I know.  I always use aliases when accessing multiple tables.  I was referring to the question, not to all possible variants of all possible queries from all possible database engines.

Comment: @Steve, I had just found the issue (ordered parameters) and was going to write it down here, but it looks like you even found that! Thanks again, everything is working as intended now.